# Cite references in figure caption without appearing in list of figures

Tags: biblatex, table-of-contents, floats, citing

**Problem:**
Citation appearing in the list of figures.

**Minimal Working Example:**

```
\begin{figure}[H]
    \centering
    \includegraphics[scale=0.6]{phases-analyse-predictive.png}
    \caption{Phases de l'Analyse prédictive \citep{Imanuel2014}}
    \label{phases-analyse-predictive}
\end{figure}
```

**Current outcome:**

[image]

**Desired outcome:**

The reference to appear in the  figure caption but not in the list of figures.

Comment: Use the short caption style with `\caption[Phases de l'Analyse]{Phases de ... \cite{Imanuel2014}`. Only the content within `[...]` will appear in the `LoF` then